# Error while using Chrome.filesystem : Chrome.fileSystem is undefind

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am trying to make chrome App which can access localfile system and keep watch on specific directory to check if any new file came or not? , so i need to use chrome.filesystem for that as per this code provided by google , its giving me error that chrome.filesystem is undefined.

Code :

```
  chooseDirButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(theEntry) {
            if (!theEntry) {
              output.textContent = 'No Directory selected.';
              return;
            }
            // use local storage to retain access to this file
            chrome.storage.local.set({'chosenFile': chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(theEntry)});
            loadDirEntry(theEntry);
          });
        });
```

Menifest File :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "short_name": "Test",
   "minimum_chrome_version": "31",
  "description": "Description for Test",

  "version": "0.0.1.0",

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  },

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    }
  },
"permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]},
    "storage","notifications","webview","http://*/*","fileSystem"
  ],
  "file_handlers": {
    "text": {
      "types": [
          "text/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {id:"fileWin", innerBounds: {width: 800, height: 500}}, function(win) {
    win.contentWindow.launchData = launchData;
  });
});
```

> How can i use chrome.filesystem ? please help. Thank you.

Comment: Edit the question to include your manifest file

Comment: Please take a look i added menifest file also.

Comment: Manifest seems okay.. Where is this code, and how are you opening the page with this code?

Comment: you can check that code here : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/filesystem-access/js/app.js

Comment: As i am building independent app, so i copied this js and use in my code , where i am calling that same function with button click event.

Comment: My point is, are you launching the app window from within `background.js`? This error looks like an app page opened improperly.

Comment: Try to remove the last `"fileSystem"` permission entry from your manifest. It's possible it conflicts with the first.

Comment: I tried that also it gives me error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chooseEntry' of undefined

Comment: Does it work if you use the sample directly?

Comment: I realize this code came from a Google example, but the way to debug things like this is to remove extraneous stuff until you get down to the bare minimum that shows the problem. Toss out all the stuff about notifications, window properties, and everything unrelated to chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry. If that works, start adding the other stuff back in until it breaks. You are drowning in unnecessary complexity! (The principle I'm using is this: 1. chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry is well know to be defined. 2. Your app does not work. 3. The answer must therefore lie between the two.)